# SimpleAuthencation throwing "Failed to reflect on the current domain's Assemblies while searching for plugins"

Tags: nunit, xamarin-studio, nancy, simple-authentication

I have a NancyFX web project using SimpleAuthentication that works fine when self-hosting from the terminal.  When I self-host from unit tests (NUnit runner with Xamarin Studio), I receive exception "Failed to reflect on the current domain's Assemblies while searching for plugin" with error message "Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies." repeated many times.

Any idea why this would fail?  This looks like the code throwing the exception is at https://github.com/SimpleAuthentication/SimpleAuthentication/blob/master/Code/SimpleAuthentication.Core/ReflectionHelpers.cs.  I tried a IntPtr.Size measurement to make sure they are running in the same 32/64 bitness in both cases (it is running 32-bit).

UPDATE: Per recommendation, I tried to run some prerelease builds to the same resulting, ending up with these binaries:

```
./Nancy.1.3-Pre1524/lib/net40/Nancy.dll
./Nancy.Authentication.Forms.1.3-Pre1524/lib/net40/Nancy.Authentication.Forms.dll
./Nancy.FlashMessages.1.0.4.0/lib/net45/Nancy.FlashMessages.dll
./Nancy.FlashMessages.Razor.1.0.4.0/lib/net45/Nancy.FlashMessages.Razor.dll
./Nancy.Hosting.Self.1.3-Pre1524/lib/net40/Nancy.Hosting.Self.dll
./Nancy.SimpleAuthentication.0.3.14/lib/net40/Nancy.SimpleAuthentication.dll
./Nancy.Viewengines.Razor.1.3-Pre1524/BuildProviders/Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.BuildProviders.dll
./Nancy.Viewengines.Razor.1.3-Pre1524/lib/net40/Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.dll
```

UPDATE:  Running the ReflectionHelpers.cs code in isolation shows that the only DLL failing to load is MonoDevelop.NUnit.  The NUnit dll is unneeded for this part anyhow.

I suppose I should contemplate https://github.com/SimpleAuthentication/SimpleAuthentication/issues/144

Comment: I'm 99% sure this is related to an issue we just fixed last night in Nancy with the way we do assembly scanning. Would you be able to test the CI build to see if it solves your problem?

Comment: I would be happy to, but could you point me to the nuget package or DLLs I should use?  thanks

Comment: We have a MyGet feed. https://www.myget.org/gallery/nancyfx/ (website) https://www.myget.org/F/nancyfx/ (feed)

Comment: https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/pull/1945 this was the fix. We have weird things happening with Sandra.SimpleValidator and FluentValidation, as well as SimpleAuthentication, all of which do reflection.

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't see a change.  Making an edit to list the versions I ended up with.

Comment: Did Nancy update to 1.3-Pre? I can only see the Nancy dependencies but not Nancy.dll itself.

Comment: Yes it did.  Sorry, copy'n'paste error.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this with `GetLoadableTypes` from this post from @haacked http://haacked.com/archive/2012/07/23/get-all-types-in-an-assembly.aspx/

And here it's the PR (https://github.com/SimpleAuthentication/SimpleAuthentication/pull/171)

I didn't had the problem with Nunit I had the problem with `Microsoft.Owin.Security.DataProtection.DpapiDataProtector` that it's not implemented in Mono....